# No such file or directory in MySQL SQL script

Tags: java, mysql, file, mysql-workbench, filepath

I have a SQL script that contains the following

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '.\\datafiles\\customers.txt' INTO TABLE Customers`
```

I open and run it in MySQL workbench and I get following error:

```
Error Code: 2. File '.\datafiles\customers.txt' not found 
  (Errcode: 2 - No such file or directory)
```

Where should I put file `customers.txt` according `'.\datafiles\customers.txt'`?

I use windows 7 and I tried the following placse:

1. `C:\datafiles`
2. `C:\temp\datafiles`
3. `C:\tem\datafiles`
4. `C:\Users\michael\datafiles`

Answer (score 1):

I think `\\` is incorrect. I Always use full path.

So if the file is in C:\datafiles\ use

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\datafiles\customers.txt' 
INTO TABLE Customers LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

Comment: `\\\` is correct because when i change it to `'C:\\datafiles\\customers.txt'` it works fine.

Comment: Can i ask why you use double \?

Comment: I did not use double \. It is in the sql script which i get it from developer company and i'm not allowed to change it. just i should know where is the correct location of file on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

Use absolute path with slash as a separator like this:

```
'C/your_folder/.../datafiles/customers.txt'
```

Comment: i don't want to change anything in the sql script. i should just put the file in the correct location in windows.

Comment: Maybe you should try to put your file in your SQL installation folder. Create the datafiles folder in there and see if it works.